# UTF-16 representation of arbitrarily long binary string

Tags: python, string, sqlite, binary, utf-16

I have binary strings and want to store them as compactly (in terms of disk space) as possible. They can be between 1 and ~1000 bits of the form '011010010110100110010101'. Storing these as "TEXT" is wasteful. I'd like to retrieve and convert them back to the original binary string. SQLite's TEXT type can be UTF-8, UTF-16BE, or UTF-16LE.

Example:

'0110101011011000001101010010111001101010011101101010100011001101001001010110010010010101010100'

Convert to :

'櫘㔮橶꣍╤锔'

for storage in the database and convert back to original binary string.

I tried many solutions but either the binary string is in the wrong format or the characters are output in some format like '\xff\xfe0\x001' which is still wasteful or only works with multiples of 8 or 16 bits.

Comment: Use zip compression and base64 to convert it to text. Then you can use ASCII or UTF-8 as the text format.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].
Moreover, clarify your specific problem or provide additional details
 to highlight exactly what you need.  As currently written,
 it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Store the binary data as a BLOB, stop trying to coerce it into a string when it's not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the binary string to an integer and track the number of bits.  A BLOB of byte data can be generated for storage as SQLITE INTEGER size would be exceeded if you have thousands of bits.

Example:

```py
import sqlite3
import os
import math

# store string of binary data packed into bytes
def insert(cur, binary):
    bit_count = len(binary)
    byte_count = math.ceil(bit_count / 8)
    byte_data = int(binary, 2).to_bytes(byte_count, 'little')
    cur.execute("insert into test values(?, ?)", (bit_count, byte_data))

# set up database
con = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('create table test(bit_count, binary)')
con.commit()

# insert some strings
for binary in ['101', '000011', '101010111011011011110001', '0110' * 250]:
    insert(cur, binary)

# retrieve, unpack and display
res = cur.execute('select * from test')
for bit_count, byte_data in res:
    integer = int.from_bytes(byte_data, 'little')
    binary = f'{integer:0{bit_count}b}'
    print(binary)
```

Output:

```
101
000011
101010111011011011110001
0110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! In my testing with 10,000 rows of 100 bit binary strings:

Store full binary string as text: .db file is 1.1 MB
Convert binary string to integer string (how I was doing it previously): .db file is 0.41 MB
This method to save as binary blob: .db file is 0.23 MB

Comment: I never would have thought of converting that entire binary string to a single integer, that's brilliant.  I just compared it to converting every 8 bits at a time and it's over 10x faster!